# ssis dtsconfig file, is there encryption

Tags: encryption, ssis, password-encryption

I remember a while ago there was some microsoft utility where you could encrypt sensitive values in an app.config file for a c# Console application.  Does anyone know if there is a way to encrypt sensitive values in a dtsconfig file?  Obviously the default dtexec.exe would have to recognize encryption in the dtsconfig file and unencrypt the variables at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not an option.

That is one of the reasons the Project Deployment Model and the SSISDB was introduced. With that, you can natively encrypt and more importantly, decrypt those values to provide credentials at run-time.